# Calculating sampling bias when estimating population proportions

Tags: estimation, sampling, sample-size

Assume a true population of size N consisting of red and blue balls, where p represents the frequency of red in the population and q represents the frequency of blue in the population.

Let's say that N=1000, p=0.7 and q=0.3.

If I take a sample from the population and observe the frequencies in the sample to infer the true population proportions, the smaller the sample the more variance there will be.

Is there a way to calculate the extent to which different sample sizes will over or underestimate the true proportions?

Comment: Can you explain why you expect a bias (as opposed to random error/variance)?

Comment: Good point. I've rephrased my question, but to answer your question, I don't know why I expect a bias, but is there a way to tell whether there is one?

Comment: Is this sampling with replacement? Or without replacement?

Comment: with replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to calculate the extent to which different sample sizes will over or underestimate the true proportions?

There is, you compute the [bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Definition) $B(\hat p)=E(\hat p-p)=E(\hat p)-p$ (here $p$ is the population proportion).

In typical situations, this bias is zero.

**Sampling with replacement**:

Specifically, if the $R$ is the number of reds in a sample of size $n$ and $\hat p=R/n$ is the sample estimate of $p$, and *if we're sampling with replacement*, then under the usual assumptions $R$ has a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution); $R\sim \text{binomial}(n,p)$.

$E(\hat p) = \frac{1}{n} E(X)=\frac{1}{n} n\cdot p=p$

**Sampling without replacement**:

On the other hand, if the $R$ is the number of reds in a sample of size $n$ and $\hat p=R/n$ is the sample estimate of $p$, and *if we're sampling without replacement*, then under the usual assumptions $R$ will have a [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) ... and, as it turns out, the bias is still 0.

In your problem $N=1000, p=0.7$ and $q=0.3$; in the notation at that link above, 
$k=R$, $K=700$, $N=1000$. Again, the sample is size $n$.

As given at that link $E(R)=nK/N = np$, and so $E(\hat p) = R/n = p$; i.e. the bias is 0.

Of course, if the bias in estimating $p$ is zero, it is also zero when estimating $q=1-p$

Comment: and E(p^) is obtained by taking samples repeatedly from the population and taking the average?

Comment: No, from the sampling properties of the estimator. You can compute (given appropriate assumptions) what the distribution you mention *would be* without actually doing it. I have made some changes above (and will likely make more)

Comment: In both cases, unless your $n$ is very large, you may want to have a look at the variance as this is in many practical situations the dominating factor for the total uncertainty.

Comment: frew, I think I am finished now.